# Definition of homotopy of slope fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homotopy-theory

I can't come up with a correct definition of homotopic slope fields (on $\mathbb{R}^2$). Idea is clear - almost the same as vector field homotopy, but problem with defining slope as a function (case when field contains lines in each direction).

Comment: What's a slope field?

Comment: A set of lines $l(z)$ continuously dependent on $z$ where $z \in U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by continuous dependence of set of lines?

Comment: It means that angle between lines at points that are close to each other is small. It can be easily formulated using $\epsilon - \delta$. 

I think that for homotopy definition we'll have to use either slope or angle, but taking in account their limitations. This is what confuses me about the problem in question.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous slope field on a plane is a continuous map into the quotient space $S^1/i$ where $i:S^1\to S^1$ is the antipodal map. This quotient space is actually $S^1$ again.

Explicitly, you can identify a line through the origin $(0,0)$ with a point on the circle $x^2+y^2 = y$: horizontal line corresponds to $(0,0)$, while other lines are mapped to the point of intersection with the circle, other than $(0,0)$.

Note that if you disallow vertical lines, then the slope field becomes a map into $S^1$ minus a point, which is contractible, so there are no interesting homotopy classes then.

Comment: Can we formulate this as definition of slope field as a $S^1$ valued map which has some specific properties?